# convert iframe into png or jpg using php

Tags: php, iframe, gdlib

Is it possible to convert an iframe(content loads from external link) content to jpg or png using PHP?

please help. It would be great if you provide sample code.

Comment: Please, provide any code you have attempted.

Comment: i used mpdf library to convert html to pdf. but i never done jpg/png from html. I have no idea  "how to start this".